# create a randbetween function that only relates to changes in 1 cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have been struggling with this for sometime and cannot find a resource online that helps.

The `rand()` and `randbetween()` function by default change every time there is a change in any value in a spreadsheet.

What I want to do is write a function that ONLY changes values (using randbetween) when the value in a single cell changes.

So the function would be something like `=Myrand(sourcecell, maxvalue, minvalue)` and will ONLY change values when `sourcecell` changes value.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The WorksheetFunction `randbetween` is volatile and will recalc every time. If you write a UDF (see below) with your own random-calculation your fine.

Answer (score 3):

A VBA User Defined Function (UDF) recalculates when one of it's parameters changes. So the `sourcecell` as `Range` should be a parameter in this User Defined Function. Then this function always recalculates when `sourcecell` changes.

The problem is that `WorksheetFunction.RandBetween` makes this UDF volatile. To avoid this we need setting `Application.Volatile False`after calling `WorksheetFunction.RandBetween`.

```
Public Function Myrand(sourcecell As Range, minvalue As Double, maxvalue As Double) As Double
 Myrand = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(minvalue, maxvalue)
 Application.Volatile False
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the following userdefined function in a standard module and it should work as desired:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MyRand(SourceCell As Range, maxval As Long, minval As Long) As Long
Randomize
MyRand = CLng(Rnd * (maxval - minval + 1)) + minval
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

This UDF uses static variant arrays to store both the last sourceCell value and the last random value it returned. If the independent sourceCell value has not changed then the UDF returns the previously calculated random value. If it has changed then the new value is stored and a new random value is returned.

This can be used multiple times throughout the workbook but if used more than once, a progressive index count of its usage must be added to the parameters; i.e every time it is used the *ndx* parameter must go up one.

```
Function myRand(sourceCell As Range, valMin As Long, valMax As Long, _
                Optional ndx As Long = 1)
    Static lastSrc As Variant, lastVal As Variant

    ndx = ndx - 1  '<~~ zero-based array; one-based count

    If Not IsArray(lastSrc) Then
        ReDim lastSrc(0 To ndx)
        ReDim lastVal(0 To ndx)
    ElseIf ndx > UBound(lastSrc) Then
        ReDim Preserve lastSrc(0 To ndx)
        ReDim Preserve lastVal(0 To ndx)
    End If

    If lastSrc(ndx) <> sourceCell.Value2 _
      Or IsEmpty(lastSrc(ndx)) Or IsEmpty(lastVal(ndx)) Then
        lastSrc(ndx) = sourceCell.Value2
        lastVal(ndx) = Application.RandBetween(valMin, valMax)
    End If

    myRand = lastVal(ndx)

End Function
```

Of course, storage of the random values cannot be maintained after closing and reopening the workbook.